# How to generate audit log for dynamodb record actions (get, update, delete)?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-serverless

I'm working on the serverless backend development and I have used aws dynamodb as database, Now I want to generate audit log for all the actions(get, update, delete) of record and store in seperate table. Is there any build in feature by aws? or how to implement it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can enable DynamoDB streams on your DynamoDB table for exactly this purpose.

From the amazon documentation:

> A DynamoDB stream is an ordered flow of information about changes to
>   items in a DynamoDB table. When you enable a stream on a table,
>   DynamoDB captures information about every modification to data items
>   in the table.
>
> Whenever an application creates, updates, or deletes items in the
>   table, DynamoDB Streams writes a stream record with the primary key
>   attributes of the items that were modified. A stream record contains
>   information about a data modification to a single item in a DynamoDB
>   table. You can configure the stream so that the stream records capture
>   additional information, such as the "before" and "after" images of
>   modified items.
>
> DynamoDB Streams helps ensure the following:
>
> Each stream record appears exactly once in the stream.
>
> For each item that is modified in a DynamoDB table, the stream records
>   appear in the same sequence as the actual modifications to the item.
>
> DynamoDB Streams writes stream records in near-real time so that you
>   can build applications that consume these streams and take action
>   based on the contents.

For more information and examples, please check out the following resources
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/dynamodb-streams-use-cases-and-design-patterns/

Comment: I understand your answer and I know about stream, but for audit log entry I need user's information who triggered operation. How can I get it in dynamodb stream? any idea.. 
thanks

Comment: That would depend on more information, how is an operation (Insert, Update, Delete) on dynamodb is triggered? Is it triggered via lambda or apigateway etc. Depending on the workflow, the key and user information needs to be stored separately. Also, keep in mind that more often than not different components are utilized using roles and users which might not uniquely identify a single person.

Comment: Operations will be triggered from Lambda, and we are using cognito for user directory. So we just want store user ID(who is responsible for the action trigger) with log entry.

Comment: If thats the case, why not emit an sns/sqs/cloudwatch event with the user information and corresponding partition & sort key of the row from the lambda and then use that to join it with the data from emitted from dynamodb streams?

Comment: Yes, sqs event can create log entry but that's completely programmable custom solution and need to manage it for each operation and each table, actually I'm looking for some central solution at database level.

Comment: @RajeshMeniya Could you please tell what solution you decided to do regarding this. I need to implement the same feature and also with cognito users.

Comment: @MarwaEldawy I have just implemented custom solution to generate audit log using lambda.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to setup CloudTrail for DynamoDB operations incl actual data change.
Please take a look at [this link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/amazon-dynamodb-now-supports-audit-logging-and-monitoring-using-aws-cloudtrail/).

Comment: It doesn't log attributes changes.